# Cordova removing my changes in main activity class after building cordova project

Tags: android, cordova, android-activity, cordova-3

I am adding some extra stuff in my cordova project's Main activity class (overriding some functions like onResume) but cordova remove them after every cordovaBuild. What should I do to prevent this behaviuor?

Comment: You coule either try to move your code in a plugin if it's possible or try to use cordova hooks to save your java file in pre-prepare and put it back in pre-compile.

Comment: @QuickFix: thanks for your response. I am very junior in cordova and android. could you please explain me a litle bit more, I am wondering if it's better to start with your first suggestion or the second one?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I have no time right now to elaborate.

If you don't know how to do plugins, the easyest is to go with hooks.

Basically hooks are scripts you can add between each step of cordova cli.

so you would add

- a script in `projecthome/.cordova/hooks/before_prepare` to save your java file
- a script in `projecthome/.cordova/hooks/before_compile` to put your java class back in place

the script are javascript nodejs scripts, I think just copy a file should not be too complicated to learn.

Here are some links about cordova cli hooks :

- http://www.mooreds.com/wordpress/archives/1197
- http://devgirl.org/2013/11/12/three-hooks-your-cordovaphonegap-project-needs/