# How to write code in main activity with cordova 3.x new command line interface

Tags: cordova, cordova-2.0.0, cordova-plugins

I want to write a new cordova plugin and I need to change the MainActivity, how to do it just with the `plugin.xml` ?

Comment: You can do it by using hooks. See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22092751/5776695)

Answer (score 0):

You can't to do only with plugin.xml. There are 3 things you need to setup.

You need to use cordova.exec API in able to communicate between javascript code and android activity.

First thing you need to declare your custom plugin in config.xml

```
<feature name="CustomPlugin">
      <param name="android-package" value="com.AndroidApacheCordovaPlugin.CustomPlugin" />
</feature>
```

Implementing the plug-in by using Java code

```
public class CustomPlugin extends CordovaPlugin {

    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) 
            throws JSONException {

        if (action.equals("sayHello")){
            try {
                String responseText = "Hello world, " + args.getString(0);
                callbackContext.success(responseText);
            } catch (JSONException e){
                callbackContext.error("Failed to parse parameters");
            }
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Calling a plug-in from JavaScript

```
function initial(){
    var name = $("#NameInput").val();
    cordova.exec(sayHelloSuccess, sayHelloFailure, "CustomPlugin", "sayHello", [name]);
}

function sayHelloSuccess(data){
    alert("OK: " + data);
}

function sayHelloFailure(data){
    alert("FAIL: " + data);
}
```